# real-time data finder - search with multiple models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

i need to make my search engine work with multiple data tables

right now get data from the model **"Registro".**

```
    public function buscador(){
        
        return view('posts.index');
        
    }
        public function search(Request $request){
            
            $results = Registro::where('cliente', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->get();
            
            return view('posts.results', compact('results'))->with(['search' => $request->search])->render();
            
        }
        public function show(Request $request){
            
            $post = Registro::findOrFail($request->id);
            return view('posts.post', compact('post'))->render();
            
       
    
}
```

can search with multiple models?

Comment: with which other model? and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to do it
1-relation between these tables
and then use conditional with
example

```
 $results = Registro::with(['relation' => function ($query) use ($request->variable) {
            $query->where('relation_column', '=', $request->variable);
        }])->where('cliente', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->get();
            
            return view('posts.results', compact('results'))->with(['search' => $request->search])->render();
```

2- get all results from registro an then map it and for each index do a search in your other table with where inside

```
  $results = Registro::where('cliente', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->get();
foreach($results as $result){
$res2=OtherTable::where('column',$result->something)->get();
if(sizeof($res2)){
//there is data do something
}
}
```